# Show that the linear function f(x)=Ax is differentiable at a

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How to show that the linear function f: $R^{n}$ $\rightarrow$ $R^{n}$, defined by ***f(x)*** = *A**x***, is differentiable at a generic point **a**, where A is a n $\times$ n matrix, and what is *D**f(a)***?

from the definition we know that a function f is differentiable at a point **a** if 
there is a matrix L such that   lim $\frac{|f(a+h)-f(a)-Lh|))}{|h|}$=0 as ***h*** $\rightarrow$ ***0***

Im trying to substitute f(a+h)=A(a+h) into the limit above and I get

lim $\frac{|A(a+h) - A(a) - Lh)|}{|h|}= \frac{|Ah - Lh|}{|h|}=\frac{|(A - L)h|}{|h|}$  and it seems h is cancel from here. Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: You can't cancel the $h$'s because $h$ is a vector, not a scalar. But if $L=A$, then the numerator is zero no matter what $h$ is, so the limit is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the linearization $L(h)$ should be the best linear approximation to the change in the function given the change $h$ in the domain. What is the best linear approximation to a linear function? You need to be clear on your claim for what $L$ is... say, I choose $L(h)=Ah$ then go from there. Otherwise I think you're on the right path.

Comment: To begin, the fundamental theorem of linear algebra tells you that there exists $A$ an $n \times n$ matrix for which $f(x)=Ax$. Of course, $A$ is just the standard matrix of $f$ as we know and love from linear algebra...